# window.open javascript encoding

Tags: javascript, encode

This is a silly question, but I really need to make sure I get  it right.

Will window.open() encode any spaces, quotes, etc that I put in the URL?

Ex:

```
window.open("http://www.web.net/cgi-bin/chk_ip.pl?ip='192.168.1.1'&userID='John Bob'&Summary='This is a test'")
```

Will the spaces and the quotes be encoded by the window.open before it takes me to the website or do I have to encode each section before I pass it to window.open?

I'm not a javascript programmer, so I need help with this.
Thank you

Comment: Easy way to test - try it and see?  Did it encode them? Would have been faster than posting a question here...

Comment: You're right, very silly question.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't. You need `encodeURIComponent` to make potentially unsafe (stuff you might be taking from user input, a database, etc.) text safe:

```
window.open("http://www.web.net/cgi-bin/chk_ip.pl?ip="
  + encodeURIComponent('192.168.1.1')
  + "&userID=" + encodeURIComponent('John Bob')
  + "&Summary=" + encodeURIComponent('This is a test')
)
```